# Mongo Aggregate - $addFields with multiplication

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I'm using the official mongo driver on golang and trying to aggregate. I want to sort entries based on the multiplication of currency and salary.

```
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)


func main () {
    //...
    aggregatePipeline := bson.A{}
    aggregatePipeline = append(aggregatePipeline, bson.D{{Key: "$addFields", Value: bson.D{{Key: "trueSalary", Value: bson.D{{"$multiply", bson.A{"salary", "currency"}}}}}}})
    aggregatePipeline = append(aggregatePipeline, bson.D{{"$sort", bson.D{{"trueSalary", -1}}}})
    cursor , _ := myCollection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), aggregatePipeline)
   // cursor returns nil.
}
```

But cursor returns nil.

My mongo entities all have "salary" and "currency" as Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go you should **always** check returned errors. That'll save you a lot of time.

```
cursor, err := myCollection.Aggregate(context.TODO(), aggregatePipeline)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output something like:

> panic: (TypeMismatch) Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string

The `$multiply` operation tries to multiply the `salary` and `currency` *strings*. Obviously this is not what you want, you want to multiply the values of the `salary` and `currency` properties, so add a `$` sign to them:

```
aggregatePipeline = append(aggregatePipeline, bson.D{{
    Key: "$addFields",
    Value: bson.D{{
        Key:   "trueSalary",
        Value: bson.D{{"$multiply", bson.A{"$salary", "$currency"}}},
    }},
}})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just checking through mongo driver source code and seeing the exact error code and trying to understand. Like you said, it would be a lot easier to just print err.Thanks!